# Unix sort run time

Tags: sorting, unix

I am using unix 'sort textfile.txt' to sort text file with more than 155,000 kb
It takes 2 min. Is there any way to make it faster or is there any alternative faster?

**Edit1:**

I try both:

```
sort -S 50% --parallel=4
```

I takes the same time "2 min"!

Comment: you can increase buffer size with the `-S` option if you have enough memory.

Comment: @karakfa Do you mean: sort -s textfile.txt?

Comment: @sara If you have GNU sort then it has a `--parallel=n` option you can leverage. Having a unix tag in your question does sound like you probably don't have GNU variant.

Comment: @sara, it's the uppercase `S` for buffer Size.

Comment: @jaypal-singh i am using cygwin in windows. What -parallel =n means?

Comment: @sara - For GNU sort, during the initial pass, it will use multiple threads (based on parallel option) for sorting to create the initial set of temporary files. Since the rest of the passes are k-way merges (with k usually == 16), multi-threading doesn't help.

Comment: @sara - alternative - Your PC probably has enough ram to hold two instance of the file, in which case a ram based sort (probably some variation of bottom up merge sort) would be faster. A sort program could also sort an array of pointers to lines in the text file, but that could be a bit slower due to cache issues.

Comment: @karakfa see edit1 please

Comment: @jaypal singh see edit1 please